# Replacing div html like toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div and i want to replace its html on hover, but on hover back i want to replace it back to it previous html.    (like toggle...)

code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner first">Hello</div>
    <div class="inner second">And</div>
    <div class="inner third">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

i try this

```
$(".inner").mouseover(function() {
    var tmpX = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).html(tmp);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: A glance at the console would state tmp is undefined...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the tmpX variable as global

```
var tmpX;
$(".inner").mouseover(function() {
    tmpX = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).html(tmpX);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x1sou51m/3/)

Comment: @sortof If you have multiple element you want to toggle, you should store the HTML in the  [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) of the element.

Answer (score 3):

You can store the old text as data property on mouseenter and retrieve it later on mouseout:

```
$('.inner').hover(function(){
  $(this).data('oldtext', $(this).text()).text("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
}, function() {
  $(this).text($(this).data('oldtext'));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cLpqy9f7/)**

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [**hover()**](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) to take advantage of `handlerIn/handlerOut`
2. Use `data-*` to preserve the original text
3. In `handlerOut`, return it to the original text

```js
$('.inner').hover(function() {
    var originalText = $(this).text();
    $(this).text('new text');
    $(this).attr('data-original-text', originalText);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).text($(this).attr('data-original-text'));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner first">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner second">And</div>
  <div class="inner third">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar, you mean in the snippet. yes it should be working I just tried it. Is it not for you?

Answer (score 1):

Mistake 1 : **Variable mistake its tmpx not tmp**

Mistake 2 : **you use var tmpx as local**

```
var tmpX;
$(".inner").mouseover(function() {
    tmpx = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).html(tmpx);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dfp70nsk/)

Comment: your tmpx is local make it as global

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo. Use this:

```
$(this).html(tmpX);
```

Make the `tmpX` variable global by pulling it out of the function!

**Full Script:**

```
var tmpX = '';
$(".inner").mouseover(function () {
    tmpX = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).html(tmpX);
});
```

Comment: @sortof Sorry, I should give the full script too. Check now!

Answer (score 1):

beside the mistake in `$(this).html(tmpX);` you need to set the tmpX var outside the mouseover function

```
var inner = $(".inner");
var tmpX = inner.text(); 
inner.mouseover(function() {            
     $(this).html( "xxxxxxxxxxxx" );
}).mouseout(function() {
     $(this).html(tmpX);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's `tmpX` and not `tmp`. Second of all, you are trying to assign `tmpX` in the `mouseout event` while it is instanced inside the `mouseover` event. `tmpX` is only available inside your `mouseover` event now.

Put the tmpX var outside of your events, like so:

```js
var tmpX;
$(".inner").mouseover(function() {            
  tmpX = $(this).html(); 
  $(this).html( "xxxxxxxxxxxx" );
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).html(tmpX);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner first">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner second">And</div>
  <div class="inner third">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```